# Prevent accessing Unix files through JVM ( any code running in application server JVM)

Tags: security, file, jvm, file-access

Is there any way that we can prevent accessing Unix files through JVM ( any code running in application server JVM).
One solution is to do it at the unix user level.
Is there any other way we configure locations somewhere?

Comment: you mean from within your app running on an app server - you want to prevent accessing unix files ?

Comment: Yes, I would need within my app however the files that I am asking are all over the file systems.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what the Java Security Policy framework is for ?  You can run any Java process with a configured Security policy configuration, which allows you to do all sorts of things like turning off access to paths (all paths even).

e.g. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/permissions.html#FilePermission

(obviously later JDK's will have this in their docs too, this one just came up in Google..).

by default the JRE will run with an open ticket security policy.